# Select entries of columns that are a certain format in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, select, subquery

I want to select/display the columns of a table that are of a certain format. I wrote the following query:

```
 SELECT 
   (SELECT 
      COLUMN_NAME 
    FROM SYS.ALL_TAB_COLS 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME='SOME_TABLE' AND DATA_TYPE IN ('DATE')) 
 FROM SOME_TABLE;
```

After the query runs for some time, I get the following error:

```
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
```

I would want a result that is something like:

```
      DATE1       DATE2
 2017-01-01  2017-01-01
 2017-01-01  2018-01-02
        ...         ...
```

Does someone know how to achieve this?

Comment: You cannot do what you want with a simple query.  You would have to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: How would this work with dynamic SQL?

Comment: You would write a stored proc that would take the table name as a parameter, build a SQL statement in a string, and then use the `DBMS_SQL` package to execute it.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of a refcursor bind variable and use the `PRINT` command to display the output from a dynamic query. This works in SQL* Plus and in Toad and SQL developer when run as script.

```
VARIABLE x refcursor; 
DECLARE 
    v_query CLOB; 
BEGIN 
    SELECT 'SELECT ' 
           || LISTAGG(column_name, ',') 
                within GROUP ( ORDER BY column_name ) 
           || ' FROM ' 
           || table_name 
    INTO   v_query 
    FROM   sys.all_tab_cols 
    WHERE  table_name = 'EMPLOYEES' 
           AND data_type IN ( 'DATE' ) 
    GROUP  BY table_name; 

    OPEN :x FOR v_query; 
END; 

/ 
PRINT x;
```

for 12c and above, you could use `DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT` on a PL/SQL cursor on the same query.

```
DECLARE 
    v_query CLOB; 
    x SYS_REFCURSOR; 
BEGIN 
    SELECT..
          ..
    OPEN x FOR v_query; 
    DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(x);
END; 
/
```

Note: If there are multiple tables in different schemas with the same name, you would need to add `owner = <schema>` as well.

Comment: I don't think this is a feasible solution for me...I am using PL/SQL version 11, Oracle DB 11g and I am not a database admin or something like that. I don't want to store procedures on the database, but I would want to execute commands like this multiple times just to analyse my data.

Comment: @guscht : The first one is an anonymous block. It does not create a stored procedure and it works in Oracle 11g and you don't have to be a database admin to run it.

Comment: I get ORA-00900 invalid SQL statement on the first line

Comment: @guscht : which tool are you using to run it?

Comment: PL/SQL developer

Comment: @guscht : You should use the command window to run sqlplus commands https://www.allroundautomations.com/plscommand.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169861/discussion-between-guscht-and-kaushik-nayak).

Answer (score 0):

Use this query to return the rows in columns and then you can use and format the columns that dynamically return with execute of EXECUTE IMMEDIATE

```
SELECT LISTAGG(COLUMN_NAME, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME) AS COLUMNA FROM (
        SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
        FROM SYS.ALL_TAB_COLS 
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'SOME_TABLE' AND DATA_TYPE IN ('DATE')
    ) SOME_TABLE

RESULT:
DATE1, DATE2
```